# How to restrict user to login on multiple browser and tab

Tags: asp.net

I have online quiz site in which i need to restrict user once he log in and if he trying 
to login on other browser or other tab with same browser.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us the effort you've put into figuring this out! SO does not create software for you, it helps you with problems you run into while programming.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to restrict user from search answers using other tab/window??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give you a hint
Restrict in another browser
"Separate browser has different session id" so in your case when you logged in store session id and if user try to logged in with another browser then you need to check for session id.

Restrict in same browser

```
if (!Session.IsNewSession && Request.UrlReferrer == null)
{
    // new tab opened
}
```

go through following link it may help you

[Check it out](http://blog.startq.com/2013/03/28/prevent-multiple-tabs-on-c-web-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

What if you just mark the user as logged in the db when they log in?  When they try to login again just check if they are currently marked as logged in, if so do not let them in.  reset that flag when they log out or after a period of time, as the might not necessarily log out, they could login do the quiz and just close the browser.